# Navigation menu not working in Child Activity

Tags: java, android, menu

so i made  a menu class and now i try to extend my others activitys from that one 
i get the button but the slide its not working in the others activitys but its apears on the left top... lest go to the code

this is my xml activity_navigatoin_menu

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="ar.com.puebloyreforma.pyr.NavigationMenu">



        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            app:headerLayout="@layout/menuheader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/caldroid_black"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
            app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            >    


        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

this is my menudrawer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:id="@+id/noticias" android:title="Noticias" android:icon="@drawable/iconews"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/calendario" android:title="Calendario" android:icon="@drawable/icocalen"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/sysacad" android:title="Sysacad" android:icon="@drawable/icosysa"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/contacto" android:title="Contacto" android:icon="@drawable/icocon"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/reglamento" android:title="Reglamento" android:icon="@drawable/icoreg"></item>

</menu>
```

and here my activity

```
package ar.com.puebloyreforma.pyr;

import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class NavigationMenu extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDL ;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mT  ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_menu);
        mDL = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer) ;
        mT = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this  , mDL ,R.string.open , R.string.close) ;
        mDL.addDrawerListener(mT);
        mT.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mT.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true ;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and this is one child activity

```
package ar.com.puebloyreforma.pyr;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class PdfsActivity extends NavigationMenu {
    public String getTarget() {
        return target;
    }

    public void setTarget(String target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    public String target ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdfs);



        Button tt , tm , tn, reg ;
        tt = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.tt);
        tm = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.tm);
        tn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.tn);
        reg = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.reg);

        final String pdfs[] = {"tm" ,
                "tt" ,
                "tn",
                "Ord1549"
        } ;

        tm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                setTarget(pdfs[0]);
                Intent hola = new Intent (PdfsActivity.this,ReglamentoActivity.class);
                hola.putExtra("TARGET", getTarget());
                startActivity(hola);
            }
        });



        tt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                setTarget(pdfs[1]);
                Intent hola = new Intent (PdfsActivity.this,ReglamentoActivity.class);
                hola.putExtra("TARGET", getTarget());
                startActivity(hola);
            }
        });

        tn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                setTarget(pdfs[2]);
                Intent hola = new Intent (PdfsActivity.this,ReglamentoActivity.class);
                hola.putExtra("TARGET", getTarget());
                startActivity(hola);
            }
        });
        reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                setTarget(pdfs[3]);
                Intent hola = new Intent (PdfsActivity.this,ReglamentoActivity.class);
                hola.putExtra("TARGET", getTarget());
                startActivity(hola);
            }
        });





    }
```

that has its onw layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="ar.com.puebloyreforma.pyr.PdfsActivity">



            <Button
            android:id="@+id/tm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MAñANA"


            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.758"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TARDE"


            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.335"
            android:layout_marginRight="123dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="NOCHE"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="68dp"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.572"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="REGLA"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tn"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.572"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.713" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Where is `onCreateOptionsMenu` method?

Comment: i do not have one , the menu works when i lauch the father activity but not on the childs

Comment: You are changing then content view itself. First of all, why do you need to have child parent architecture for Activities?

Comment: saw in documentation that  the best way to aply a menu to all activitys its making a father class then the childs will have the menu ,  i think the problem its related to the child owns layouts but i cant figuredout how keep both the layout of the menu and the activitylayout .

Comment: Since you are beginner in this. Can you tell me what exactly you are trying to achieve? Any App reference you can give? May be there is a better solution that you can have.

Comment: im trying to make this activity NavigatoinMenu works in every other activitys  keeping the slide menu for all the application .  the same as telegram that the menu can be slide or open by a button in the top left.

Comment: Then why ain't you using fragment with activity? What you are trying to implement is not a good practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me post my code with which I manage to obtain NavigationDrawer in child activity.

**MyAppCompatActivity**(ParentActivity `class`)

```
public abstract class MyAppCompatActivity extends BaseAppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
    CoordinatorLayout activityParentBase = (CoordinatorLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer, null);
    RelativeLayout content = (RelativeLayout) activityParentBase.findViewById(R.id.content);
    setContentView(activityParentBase);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, content, true);
    super.setContentView(activityParentBase);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            MyAppCompatActivity.this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.nav_item1) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_item2) {

            }
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }
    });
    }
}
```

**activity_navigation_drawer.xml**(ParentActivity `XML`)

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MyAppCompatActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
         app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:openDrawer="start">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/content" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation_drawer" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**ChildNavigationActivity** (ChildActivity `class`)

```
public class ChildNavigationActivity extends MyAppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_child_navigation);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); //we have included "toolbar" in the parentactivity xml. So not need to do it in childactivity xml.
    /**NOTE: Do Not use "setSupportActionBar(toolbar)" since you have already done it in your parent activity*/
    toolbar.setTitle("ChildNavigationActivity");

    }

}
```

**activity_child_navigation**(ChildActivity `XML`)

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ChildNavigationActivity">

    <!--Put all your ChildActivity Widgets here-->

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: ty ill try this and  reply my results , ty again for taking ur time to do this

Comment: I LOVE U MAN ! it s woking perfectly have some issues with  style xml but at a little resech i fixed changin theme to  ...light.NoActionBar